# ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine() null point exception

Tags: java

I create under eclipse using activiti plugin my activiti project and I create the process
then under activiti explorer (http://com.supcom:8080/activiti-explorer) I have imported this project and I make the export in order to obtain **MyProcess.bpmn20.xml**

I create another web project, I make MyProcess.bpmn20.xml under com.test  package

in lib folder I put this jar  **activiti-engine-5.13.jar**

when I run this java class I have Exception in thread **"main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

the  **ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();**   is null

this is the java  test in order to deploy my process :

```
 ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
 RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
       repositoryService.createDeployment()
       .addClasspathResource("com/test/MyProcess.bpmn20.xml")
       .deploy();
```

**Updated :**

I make activiti-cfg.jar  in lib folder

this jar contains activit.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">
  
    <!-- Database configurations -->
 <property name="databaseType" value="postgresql" />
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti8" />
<property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
<property name="jdbcUsername" value="postgres" />
<property name="jdbcPassword" value="postgres" />
    
  </bean>

</beans>
```

**My process.bpmn.xml is deployed under activiti-explorer  which is worked with postgress**

by modified db.properties

```
db=postgres
jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti8
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=postgres
```

this is my  java class test :

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException;
import org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException;
import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine;
import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngineConfiguration;
import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngineInfo;
//import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines;
import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineInfoImpl;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public abstract class ProcessEngines {
  
  //private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessEngines.class);
  
  public static final String NAME_DEFAULT = "default";
  
  protected static boolean isInitialized = false; 
  protected static Map<String, ProcessEngine> processEngines = new HashMap<String, ProcessEngine>();
  protected static Map<String, ProcessEngineInfo> processEngineInfosByName = new HashMap<String, ProcessEngineInfo>();
  protected static Map<String, ProcessEngineInfo> processEngineInfosByResourceUrl = new HashMap<String, ProcessEngineInfo>();
  protected static List<ProcessEngineInfo> processEngineInfos = new ArrayList<ProcessEngineInfo>();
  
  /** Initializes all process engines that can be found on the classpath for 
   * resources <code>activiti.cfg.xml</code> (plain Activiti style configuration)
   * and for resources <code>activiti-context.xml</code> (Spring style configuration). */
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
          ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
            RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
        
    }
  public synchronized static void init() {
    if (!isInitialized()) {
      if(processEngines == null) {
        // Create new map to store process-engines if current map is null
        processEngines = new HashMap<String, ProcessEngine>();        
      }
      ClassLoader classLoader = ReflectUtil.getClassLoader();
      Enumeration<URL> resources = null;
      try {
        resources = classLoader.getResources("activiti.cfg.xml");
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ActivitiIllegalArgumentException("problem retrieving activiti.cfg.xml resources on the classpath: "+System.getProperty("java.class.path"), e);
      }
      
      // Remove duplicated configuration URL's using set. Some classloaders may return identical URL's twice, causing duplicate startups
      Set<URL> configUrls = new HashSet<URL>();
      while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        configUrls.add( resources.nextElement() );
      }
      for (Iterator<URL> iterator = configUrls.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        URL resource = iterator.next();
      //  log.info("Initializing process engine using configuration '{}'",  resource.toString());
        initProcessEnginFromResource(resource);
      }
      
      try {
        resources = classLoader.getResources("activiti-context.xml");
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ActivitiIllegalArgumentException("problem retrieving activiti-context.xml resources on the classpath: "+System.getProperty("java.class.path"), e);
      }
      while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL resource = resources.nextElement();
       // log.info("Initializing process engine using Spring configuration '{}'",  resource.toString());
        initProcessEngineFromSpringResource(resource);
      }

      setInitialized(true);
    
    } else {
   //   log.info("Process engines already initialized");
    }
  }

  protected static void initProcessEngineFromSpringResource(URL resource) {
    try {
      Class< ? > springConfigurationHelperClass = ReflectUtil.loadClass("org.activiti.spring.SpringConfigurationHelper");
      Method method = springConfigurationHelperClass.getMethod("buildProcessEngine", new Class<?>[]{URL.class});
      ProcessEngine processEngine = (ProcessEngine) method.invoke(null, new Object[]{resource});
      
      String processEngineName = processEngine.getName();
      ProcessEngineInfo processEngineInfo = new ProcessEngineInfoImpl(processEngineName, resource.toString(), null);
      processEngineInfosByName.put(processEngineName, processEngineInfo);
      processEngineInfosByResourceUrl.put(resource.toString(), processEngineInfo);
      
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ActivitiException("couldn't initialize process engine from spring configuration resource "+resource.toString()+": "+e.getMessage(), e);
    } 
  }
 
  /**
   * Registers the given process engine. No {@link ProcessEngineInfo} will be 
   * available for this process engine. An engine that is registered will be closed
   * when the {@link ProcessEngines#destroy()} is called.
   */
  public static void registerProcessEngine(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    processEngines.put(processEngine.getName(), processEngine);
  }
  
  /**
   * Unregisters the given process engine.
   */
  public static void unregister(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    processEngines.remove(processEngine.getName());
  }

  private static ProcessEngineInfo initProcessEnginFromResource(URL resourceUrl) {
    ProcessEngineInfo processEngineInfo = processEngineInfosByResourceUrl.get(resourceUrl.toString());
    // if there is an existing process engine info
    if (processEngineInfo!=null) {
      // remove that process engine from the member fields
      processEngineInfos.remove(processEngineInfo);
      if (processEngineInfo.getException()==null) {
        String processEngineName = processEngineInfo.getName();
        processEngines.remove(processEngineName);
        processEngineInfosByName.remove(processEngineName);
      }
      processEngineInfosByResourceUrl.remove(processEngineInfo.getResourceUrl());
    }

    String resourceUrlString = resourceUrl.toString();
    try {
   //   log.info("initializing process engine for resource {}", resourceUrl);
      ProcessEngine processEngine = buildProcessEngine(resourceUrl);
      String processEngineName = processEngine.getName();
    //  log.info("initialised process engine {}", processEngineName);
      processEngineInfo = new ProcessEngineInfoImpl(processEngineName, resourceUrlString, null);
      processEngines.put(processEngineName, processEngine);
      processEngineInfosByName.put(processEngineName, processEngineInfo);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
   //   log.error("Exception while initializing process engine: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
      processEngineInfo = new ProcessEngineInfoImpl(null, resourceUrlString, getExceptionString(e));
    }
    processEngineInfosByResourceUrl.put(resourceUrlString, processEngineInfo);
    processEngineInfos.add(processEngineInfo);
    return processEngineInfo;
  }

  private static String getExceptionString(Throwable e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    return sw.toString();
  }

  private static  ProcessEngine buildProcessEngine(URL resource) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
      inputStream = resource.openStream();
      ProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromInputStream(inputStream);
      return processEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine();
      
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ActivitiIllegalArgumentException("couldn't open resource stream: "+e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
    //  IoUtil.closeSilently(inputStream);
    }
  }
  
  /** Get initialization results. */
  public static List<ProcessEngineInfo> getProcessEngineInfos() {
    return processEngineInfos;
  }

  /** Get initialization results. Only info will we available for process engines
   * which were added in the {@link ProcessEngines#init()}. No {@link ProcessEngineInfo}
   * is available for engines which were registered programatically.
  */
  public static ProcessEngineInfo getProcessEngineInfo(String processEngineName) {
    return processEngineInfosByName.get(processEngineName);
  }

  public static ProcessEngine getDefaultProcessEngine() {
    return getProcessEngine(NAME_DEFAULT);
  }

  /** obtain a process engine by name.  
   * @param processEngineName is the name of the process engine or null for the default process engine.  */
  public static ProcessEngine getProcessEngine(String processEngineName) {
    if (!isInitialized()) {
      init();
    }
    return processEngines.get(processEngineName);
  }
  
  /** retries to initialize a process engine that previously failed.
   */
  public static ProcessEngineInfo retry(String resourceUrl) {
   // log.debug("retying initializing of resource {}", resourceUrl);
    try {
      return initProcessEnginFromResource(new URL(resourceUrl));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new ActivitiIllegalArgumentException("invalid url: "+resourceUrl, e);
    }
  }
  
  /** provides access to process engine to application clients in a 
   * managed server environment.  
   */
  public static Map<String, ProcessEngine> getProcessEngines() {
    return processEngines;
  }
  
  /** closes all process engines.  This method should be called when the server shuts down. */
  public synchronized static void destroy() {
    if (isInitialized()) {
      Map<String, ProcessEngine> engines = new HashMap<String, ProcessEngine>(processEngines);
      processEngines = new HashMap<String, ProcessEngine>();
      
      for (String processEngineName: engines.keySet()) {
        ProcessEngine processEngine = engines.get(processEngineName);
        try {
          processEngine.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //  log.error("exception while closing {}", (processEngineName==null ? "the default process engine" : "process engine "+processEngineName), e);
        }
      }
      
      processEngineInfosByName.clear();
      processEngineInfosByResourceUrl.clear();
      processEngineInfos.clear();
      
      setInitialized(false);
    }
  }
  
  public static boolean isInitialized() {
    return isInitialized;
  }
  
  public static void setInitialized(boolean isInitialized) {
    ProcessEngines.isInitialized = isInitialized;
  }
}
```

as you see  in main class I call this methods :

```
init();
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
```

but also `ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine()` is null

when I make the debug in this line :

```
 ProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromInputStream(inputStream);
```

inputStream contains :

```
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@3820e

sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection:jar:file:/F:/workspace/testwebProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/activiti-cfg.jar!/activiti.cfg.xml
```

but after running this line it will be catched by this line

```
  } catch (Throwable e) {
     processEngineInfo = new ProcessEngineInfoImpl(null, resourceUrlString, getExceptionString(e));
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your activiti.cfg.xml?

Comment: thank you for your response, I have updated my question, but I still have null point exception error

Comment: error is related to this line :     ProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromInputStream(inputStream);
        imputstream  when I debug contain  jar:file:/F:/workspace/testwebProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/activiti-cfg.jar!/activiti.cfg.xml

Comment: Can you please post the entire stacktrace? I just can't find the error either...

Comment: Another thing, try coping the a‌​ctiviti.cfg.xml to your META-INF folder, maybe it just can't find the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You might lack camunda configuration in your servlet configuration, e.g. in tomcat `server.xml` add a `TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap` listener and resources for BPM Process Engine Service, `ProcessEngineService` and `ProcessApplicationService`.